# copiar campo de una tabla a otra php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hola quisiera saber como puedo terminar de buena manera la inserción de un campo que ya esta insertado en otra tabla, en esta nueva, llevo lo que mostrare a continuación:

```
$copcod = mysqli_query("insert into tabla_destino (select id, código from 
tabla_emisora where id=id)");
```

(donde id tiene que ser el de la sesión actual y al mismo tiempo el de la tabla original)

Comment: ¿A qué campos quieres asignar esos dos campos obtenidos con el `SELECT`? ¿Podrías dar más información acerca de la estructura para poder montarte correctamente la consulta?

Comment: el select es para asignar a que el id sea el mismo en ambas tablas, y código es para hacer su respectiva inserción desde tabla_emisora a tabla_destino, nose si me explico bien

Comment: Sé para qué sirve el `SELECT` y tu consulta de referencia no sirve para nada porque lo importante del `INSERT / SELECT` es la asignación de campos y si no coinciden los campos obtenidos con los de la tabla `tabla_destino` entonces fallará la consulta. ¿Podrías decirme a qué campos de `tabla_destino` quieres asignar `id` y `código` de la tabla `tabla_emisora`? ¿Hay otros campos que requieran de un valor? (valores `NOT NULL` sin un valor por defecto, por ejemplo). Si nos compartes el `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tabla>` de las tablas podremos ayudarte a montar correctamente la consulta.

Comment: Para tratar de entender un poco mejor: vos tenes dos tablas en las cuales ya hay registros en ambas y queres "copiar" datos de una tabla a otra cuando el id de los registros coincidan?

Comment: Asi es tengo dos tablas de la cual tabla_emisora tiene un campo codigo, el cual tengo que copiarlo a tabla_destino, siempre y cuando sus id sean iguales este id tambien tiene que ser el mismo de la sessiom actual

Answer (score 0):

La sentencia correcta para un INSERT con SELECT es la siguiente

```
INSERT INTO tabla1 (tabla1_campo1, tabla1_campo2,...)
SELECT tabla2_campo1, tabla2_campo2,... FROM tabla2
WHERE condiciones
```

Es importante saber que los tipos de datos deberían ser iguales o al menos compatibles.

Por ejemplo, este insert fallaría si tabla1_campo1 fuera de tipo INTEGER y tabla2_campo1 fuera de tipo CHAR.

Así pues, es importante revisar el orden de los campos para que coincidan las columnas.

También es posible utilizar alguna función de conversión y de esa manera insertar números como caracteres. Pero si necesitases tal cosa ya nos avisa. De momento prueba a utilizar esta sintaxis verificando bien las columnas y el orden que pones en la parte del INTO y en la de la SELECT.